# How to change the default text color with grommet io?

Tags: grommet

What variable do I have to set in my theme to change the base font color? 
Something like:

```
const theme = deepMerge(base, {
  global: {
    font: {
      family: 'sans-serif',
    },
    color: '#eeeeee',
  },
});
```

or

```
const theme = deepMerge(base, {
  global: {
    font: {
      family: 'sans-serif',
      color: '#eeeeee',
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I will start using Grommet soon and am researching about it.

Maybe have a look here, this might be helpful: https://github.com/atanasster/grommet-nextjs/issues/1

```
<Button theme={{ global: { colors: { darkBackground: { text: 'red' } } } }} primary={true} label='Submit' onClick={() => {}} />
```

Comment: Please be mindful you are not sharing the Grommet Button API, the project you shared isn't grommet-core. Grommet Button, doesn't accept a prop of `theme`.

Answer (score 0):

The basic text color would be set on `global.colors.text` on your customTheme object as follows:

```
const customTheme = {
  global: {
    colors: {
      // all colors could be either a string or a dark and light object
      text: {
        dark: 'teal',
        light: 'purple',
      },
      // or simply as a string:
      // text: "#456789",
    },
  },
};

const Example = () => (
  <Grommet theme={customTheme}>
    <Box gap="medium" pad="small">
      <Text>
         Custom text color according to how it is defined on 
         global.colors.text
      </Text>
    </Box>
  </Grommet>
);
```

For more extensive color settings, you can also define your own custom colors on `global.colors` or override any color that is mentioned on the grommet documentations.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure to set `global.colors.background`. If not set, `global.colors.text` will have no effect.